# LinQ DataContext - The operation cannot be performed during a call to SubmitChanges

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext, submitchanges

The code which is throwing exception is extremely easy - this is very regular insert and then submit changes statement which looks:

```
context.tb_dayErrorLog.InsertOnSubmit(data);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

So really nothing special. This statement is executed about 50 thousands times a day without any problem, but:
about 6 - 10 times a day it finishes with:

The operation cannot be performed during a call to SubmitChanges.

```
StackTrace:    at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.CheckNotInSubmitChanges()
at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.InsertOnSubmit(TEntity entity)
```

I was trying to find out what that can be but can't find a clue
This behavior  is very not deterministic politely saying - how it can finish 50k times correctly and few times not?

`DataContext` was firstly initialized as a static one, and then reused for all the calls, so I was thinking maybe that's the problem. Then I changed it to be initialized with every call but results are quite similar. Still few exceptions a day.

Any idea?

---

some additions:
function looks like:

```
public override bool Log(ErrorLogData logData)
    {

        try
        {
            logData.ProcessID = _processID;
            //Create new log dataset
            var data = new DataRecord
            {
                application = logData.Application,
                date = DateTime.Now,
                Other = logData.Other,
                process = logData.ProcessName,
                processid = logData.ProcessID,
                severity = logData.Severity,
                username = logData.UserName,
                Type = (short)logData.ErrorType
            };


            var context = new DataContext(ConnectionString);

            context.tb_dayErrorLog.InsertOnSubmit(data);
            context.SubmitChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log log in eventviewer
            LogEvent(logData.ToString(), ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

so simple record initialization and then insert.

As I wrote in the comment, while making same thing by Ado.Net and SqlCommand this problem is not occuring...

So my curiosity makes me think why?

Comment: I think we need some extra information. Is this code running, let's say, on a scheduled task? Is it possible that multiple instances of this program run concurrently? It's just a guess anyway, with only 2 lines of code to analyze.

Comment: This is very simple function which does just one record insert, initializing DC for every call, so whatever it is concurrent or not?
The funny thing is that when I execute a db call with old good ADO.Net SqlCommand then the problem is not occuring...

So opening connection in old Ado.Net is always assigning a new conn to you. Does
context = new DataContext(ConnectionString);
isn't doing same thing?

Comment: Start by Disposing of the context ASAP. See sgmore's answer

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a threading issue where you are calling Log and hence SubmitChanges on one thread when another thread is in the middle of SubmitChanges.

I suspect your DataContext is still a global static variable.

Try changing your Log method to

```
using (var context = new DataContext(ConnectionString))
{
    context.tb_dayErrorLog.InsertOnSubmit(data);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, in the previous function in the first post I typed it wrongly, because there is 
var context = new DataContext(ConnectionString);
(it was without 'var' keyword - but it was only mistake by typing a post) - so actually it makes the same what you are proposing

Comment: ok, maybe not same, because it is not disposing directly after the end of the call, but DataContext is disposed anyway later by GarbageColector.
But anyway I will try to dispose it this way, because I'm out of the other solutions anyway...

Answer (score 0):

@SgMoore points to concurrency problem and in my case it really was. If that's the case another approach is to use lock like this:

```
 String lockValue = "";

  lock (lockValue)
  {
       context.tb_dayErrorLog.InsertOnSubmit(data);//UPDATE: concurrency error can  occur here too
       context.dc.SubmitChanges(); 
  }
```